# How can I count occurrences in a certain column for current time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, data-science

My Dataframes looks like this -

```
Column 1
Event-Won
Event-Won
Event-lost
Event-Won
Event-lost
```

I want to count number of events (won/lost) and display count on a certain timestamp (current time). I am using this code for it and its giving me count. But I want to take a timestamp as input and want to see how many occurrences are there on that particular timestamp.

```
from collections import Counter
countval['newValue'].value_counts()
```

My desired output will be -

```
Input- current time (timestamp 1)
Output - Event-won -3 
         Event-lost - 2

Input - future time (timestamp 2)
Output - Event-won - 5
         Event-lost - 3
```

I would appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] to illustrate the specific issue.

Comment: At least show what your expected output is.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to second first , then we do `mean` and `median`

```
pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_timedelta(s).dt.total_seconds().median(),unit='s')
Out[927]: Timedelta('39 days 17:54:00')
pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_timedelta(s).dt.total_seconds().mean(),unit='s')
Out[928]: Timedelta('36 days 23:35:10')
```